# How to call jquery function for alternate gmaps infowindow?

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I want to call jQuery function like modal box instead of using gmaps infowindows.
How can I do that?

Here is the code, it's still using default infowindows:

```
var marker;

function initialize() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);

    GEvent.addListener(map, "click", function(overlay, latlng) {
          if (latlng) {
        marker = new GMarker(latlng, {draggable:true});
        GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
          var html = "<table>" +
                     "<tr><td>Name:</td> <td><input type='text' id='name'/> </td> </tr>" +
                     "<tr><td>Address:</td> <td><input type='text' id='address'/></td> </tr>" +
                     "<tr><td>Type:</td> <td><select id='type'>" +
                     "<option value='bar' SELECTED>bar</option>" +
                     "<option value='restaurant'>restaurant</option>" +
                     "</select> </td></tr>" +
                     "<tr><td></td><td><input type='button' value='Save & Close' onclick='saveData()'/></td></tr>" +
                         "";



          marker.openInfoWindow(html);
        });
        map.addOverlay(marker);
      }
    });

  }
}
```

The `infowindows` dialog from this code :

```
   marker.openInfoWindow(html);
```

Help me, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to create a dialog div like this (anywhere in the page):

```
<div id="dialog" style="display:none"></div>
```

Then, Instead of

```
marker.openInfoWindow(html);
```

You should do

```
$("#dialog").html(html);
$("#dialog").dialog();
```

(You must have included the proper scripts, of course)

More info on jQuery dialog [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).